# JFrame 'Console' style text

Tags: java, swing, text, jframe

I have probably a quick question but here it goes.  I am making a game (new to programming) and I want a text field in the middle of my game that I can easily add to kind of like a console. You will be able to view the beginning from late into the game.

Example:
Welcome to the game.
*Added when you click a button*
More text is added.
*You click a different button*
More text is added.

I am currently using a JLabel for this but it's a .setText which is inconvenient when I want to have tons of text throughout my game.  As well, how could I add a scrollbar to this?

Comment: see [scrollpane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html). Also, you can create a font of type "Console" (I think that's a font type).

Comment: I would recommend a read-only (set editable to false) JTextArea or JTextPane. They come with scrollbars anyway. And yes, as Quincunx said, Console should be a stock font type unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @Quincunx, How would I add text to it, without doing a .setText?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess you are looking for  `JTextArea` .